Worst-case analysis using confidence intervals
I need to state something about the minimum expected value of the population with a certain confidence, and I'm not sure if I understand the process correctly.
Say I have a process with a strict minimum required value. I sample the process and get the following values
19.7; 20.4; 19.6; 17.8; 18.5; 18.9; 18.3; 18.9; 19.5; 21.95

The 95% confidence interval for the mean (19.355) is [18.5; 20.21].
The 95% confidence interval for the standard deviation (1.188) is [0.8172; 2.1688].
Does this mean that I can be 95% that the populations actual distribution is within the full window of confidence intervals? In other words, the "worst-case" being a distribution with mean=18.5 and stdev=2.1688, and therefore my lowest expected value at the 95% value would be 18.5-2*2.1688 = 14.16?
It feels like I'm somehow counting uncertainties double, but I can't figure it out.

Your intuition that you are double counting the uncertainty is indeed correct. What you are looking for is a Tolerance Interval, that is a confidence interval for a proportion.
Let's assume that your data is "normal enough" (that seems to be the road you are taking; with a sample size of 10 it is hard to asses, but, fwiw, a normality test (Anderson Darling) does not reject normality (p=0.458)). The low bound of a normal tolerance interval for 95% of the population, at a 95% confidence level, is 15.897. That means that you are 95% confident that at least 95% of the population will have a value of no less than 15.897. Of course, for a different proportion (e.g. 99%) and a different confidence (e.g. 99%), you would get a different lower limit (e.g. 13.327).
You can find good references on normal tolerance intervals here (NIST) or here (Air Force).

Excellent, thanks. Not sure why this isn't more prevalent in engineering. Tolerance intervals seem way more useful in many cases.

It is indeed much more useful than, say, tests of the mean. It is not very often (enough) taught in statistics courses/textbooks. But it is quite often used in engineering (the field I come from) and in manufacturing/quality.
